# How to concatenate a string with a count variable and an increment operator in a print statement?

Tags: swift, concatenation, string-interpolation

I have a string variable. I need the variable to change. What I thought of was to declare a count variable with an increment operator. I used it in a print statement but it doesn't work.

I need it to print iOS1 to iOS10 but instead it just prints iOS ten times.

Basically I need it to print 10 different strings based off of the one iOS variable.

```
let iOS = "iOS"

var count = 0

for num in 1...10 {
    print("\(iOS)" + String(count += 1))
}

/*
I want to print
iOS1
iOS2
iOS3
iOS4
iOS5
iOS6
iOS7
iOS8
iOS9
iOS10
*/
```

I also tried to use string interpolation but nahhh it didn't work either

```
for num in 1...10 {
    print("\(iOS)" + "String(\(count += 1))")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the index variable `num`. It's incremented automatically

```
let iOS = "iOS"

for num in 1...10 {
  print("\(iOS)\(num)")
}
```

or

```
(1...10).forEach { print(iOS + "\($0)") }
```

PS: Use this if the `count` variable is required

```
var count = 0

for _ in 1...10 {
  count += 1
  print(iOS + "\(count)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The problem is I have to use the count variable. This is actually something from a much bigger project that I need to use and I shortened it instead of uploading all the code. The count variable is imperative. I'm going to up vote your answer because it is 100% correct but i can;t apply it for my scenario.

Comment: Then add at least the code to show how the count variable is imperative. Consider that almost all C-style `for` loops can be replaced with native sequence loops in Swift

Comment: i just noticed something in my code. I might be able to use your original answer. I'll know in 5 min.

Comment: It actually works but I ran into another issue. Now that I think about it I could've phrased my question differently and just extracted a smaller part of my code. I'm going to rephrase the question now but yes your answer works!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some sort of confusion about exactly what you're asking for.  Do you want the value of the string variable `iOS` to be updated each time the loop loops?

```
var iOS = "iOS"

for num in 1...10 {
    iOS = "iOS\(num)"
    print(iOS)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. vadian's answer worked perfectly. Yours works perfectly to though! I'll up vote you.